# Is there any way to apply same style to different XML tags / highlight syntax like in editor?

Tags: css, xml

A user can upload a custom `xml` file, with different elements, each file can look different and structured differently. For example:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

or

```
<file>
<name>Tove</name>
<lastname>Jani</lastname>
<title>Reminder</title>
<content>Don't forget me this weekend!</content>
</file>
```

How can I apply the same style to the two different `xml` files? color the text orange and the tags blue, for example.

EDIT:
Based on `BoltClock` comment, I want to hightlight the syntax itself, just like it it seen in an editor of some sort.

Comment: "color the text orange and the tags blue" Sounds like you're looking for syntax highlighting? Like the colors you see when you're looking at the XML itself in an editor, or here.

Comment: Exactly, didnt know how to describe the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap everything into another element (i.e. ) and then go from there:

```css
info > *:nth-child(odd) {
  display: block;
  background: orange;
}

info > *:nth-child(even) {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
}

info > * > *:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

info > * > *:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}

info > * > *:nth-child(3) {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

info > * > *:nth-child(3):after {
  content: ' :';
}

info > * > *:nth-child(4) {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<info>
  <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>

  <file>
    <name>Tove</name>
    <lastname>Jani</lastname>
    <title>Reminder</title>
    <content>Don't forget me this weekend!</content>
  </file>
</info>
```

Hope this helps.